# .htaccess rewrite does not work with my css

Tags: css, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have an issue with rewrite mode, and searching for solutions in this forum with no success so far.

I am working with the localhost (where friendly url for prestashop works), but in other webpage do not work. The .htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^see_product/(.+)/(.+) see_product.php?idtit=$1&title=$2
```

But the CSS file do not work now.

The path of the CSS is in `http://localhost/library/style/mystyle.css`
the path to see one product is `http://localhost/library/see_product.php?idtit=21221`.

I really appreciate someone could assist me in this matter because I have spent days trying to solve this problem but anything works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have multiviews turned off, above `RewriteEngine On`, add:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

The make sure you have the correct relative URL base, so in your page headers (between the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/library/" />
```

Comment: I really thank you your help !!!!!!!!!, it works for me. What worked for me in special was <base href="/library/" />. What do i have to do when i  upload this to the hosting?. The url will now be www.mysite.com/see_product.php?idtit=22312. Do i have to place the tag <base href="/mysite.com/" />  ?

Comment: I really thank you your help, it worksw for me. What worked for me in special was <i><base href="/library/" /></i>

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Apache to not rewrite existing files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^see_product/(.+)/(.+) see_product.php?idtit=$1&title=$2
```

This won't parse your rule if the url points to a valid directory or a valid file